# Oracle Listener Name without checking listener.ora file for windows

Tags: oracle, powershell

I need to find the oracle database listener name in windows through script without reading any file present in oracle home directory,may be through services or processes in windows like we are able to get it in Linux as:-

```
ps -ef|grep tnslsnr
```

which gives an output like

```
root     18489 14155  0 11:22 pts/1    00:00:00 grep tnslsnr
oracle   19857     1  0 Jul22 ?        00:00:50 /opt/app/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -inherit
```

Here listener name is LISTENER i.e. the name after "/opt/app/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr"

Is it possible either through powershell script or batch script ?

Comment: I can't test it because I have not listener running but you can try `gps | select *` or `gwmi -class win32_process | select * ` and search in that output.

Comment: gps | select * or gwmi -class win32_process | select *
These commands do list the TNSLSNR process but i couldn't find the listener name "LISTENER"(this is the listener name that shows up in lsnrctl status command) associated with it

Comment: Perhaps that information is not available through ordinary means but if you can take a dump of the process and post the results somewhere I'm happy to take a stab at it. *(you can use procdump from sysinternal to create a dump. Something like procdump -ma tnslsnr <outputfile>)*

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle "lsnrctl"/"netca" tools will create the listener service short name/alias with fairly predictable nomenclature (very least should have the words "Oracle" and "LISTENER" in there even if u specify default/no listener name), and service names are readily available from the Registry. With PowerShell, you could do something like:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object Name -Match "^\w*<listener name>\w*$" | Select Name
Get-Service | Where-Object Name -Match "^\w*<instance key>\w*<listener name>\w*$" | Select Name
Get-Service | Where-Object Name -Match "^\w*<instance key>\w*LISTENER\w*$" | Select Name
Get-Service | Where-Object Name -Match "^\w*Oracle\w*LISTENER\w*$" | Select Name
```

Where:
"<listener name>" --> listener name used when created using "netca" or "lsnrctl.
"<instance key>" --> Key name of the Oracle instance, minus the "key_" prefix (Registry key).

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions) ("Word character: \w" section) for a description of PowerShell RegEx word character ("\w") matching; basically letts/nums/punctuation (mainly underscore) ie chars Oracle allows/uses to form a legal listener name.  You can also use the "." to consume any character.